# Receive null device token sometimes

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, devicetoken

I'm currently working on project that allows user to receive push notifications whenever there is something new on the user account. I'm using Parse as my push notifications service. I'm having no problem until recently our server starting to receive empty token device on every push notification registration, this problem is not always happening. So when I tried the app on my device it just run as it should but when my app tested on our client device , our server receive an empty token device for that client user. How can this happen? How can I fix this? And how is the best practice to get and set the device token?

Here is my code in appdelegate:

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken{
const unsigned *tokenBytes = [deviceToken bytes];
NSString *token = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x",
                            ntohl(tokenBytes[0]), ntohl(tokenBytes[1]), ntohl(tokenBytes[2]),
                            ntohl(tokenBytes[3]), ntohl(tokenBytes[4]), ntohl(tokenBytes[5]),
                            ntohl(tokenBytes[6]), ntohl(tokenBytes[7])];

//function for saving device token to server
[[ASEngine defaultEngine] setCurrentDeviceToken:token];
if([[ASEngine defaultEngine] currentCredential] != nil) {
    [[ASEngine defaultEngine] webStoreDeviceToken:token];

}

//save current instalation to parse
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
[currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
[currentInstallation saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error e current installation: %@", error);
}];

//save device token locally
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:deviceToken forKey:@"deviceToken"];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

An empty token wont ever be generated,
iOS provides [didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:) method which is being probably called in your case, please make sure to check that for any errors in token creation.

Comment: So, you suggest me to request for another device token inside didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError ?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens when your device is not connected to internet.
Make sure your device is connected to internet.

Comment: What if connection is slow? it can happen?

Comment: No ideally it returns null only if you doesn't have internet connection.Speed doesn't matters.

Comment: But in my case the null token saved to our server after receiving null device token, it means that the device have a internet connection.